# how to combine two linq to entity queries in just one query?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, join, group-by, linq-to-entities

```
  var CJTDebTransaction = from d in db.DebtorTransactions
                                 join c in db.CarJackaTrackas on d.ProductID equals c.pkfCjtID
                                 join a in db.Agents on c.AgentID equals a.pkfAgentID
                                 join s in db.SalesReps on c.SalesRepId equals s.pkfSrID
                                 where d.TransTypeID==1 && d.Product==1
                                 select new { d.Amount, d.TransTypeID, Name=a.Name.Trim(), a.pkfAgentID,s.pkfSrID,salesrepName=s.Name} into debtRec
                                 group debtRec by new { debtRec.TransTypeID, debtRec.Name, debtRec.pkfAgentID,debtRec.salesrepName,debtRec.pkfSrID} into debtRecGroup
                                 orderby debtRecGroup.Key.Name
                                 select new 
                                 { 
                                  Sum= debtRecGroup.Sum(model=>model.Amount),
                                  TransTypeId=debtRecGroup.Key.TransTypeID ,
                                  AgentId=debtRecGroup.Key.pkfAgentID,
                                  AgentName=debtRecGroup.Key.Name,
                                  SalesrepId=debtRecGroup.Key.pkfSrID,
                                  SalesRepName=debtRecGroup.Key.salesrepName 
                                 };



            var WntyDebTransaction = from d in db.DebtorTransactions
                                     join w in db.Warranties on d.ProductID equals w.Id
                                     join a in db.Agents on w.fldAgentID equals a.pkfAgentID
                                     join s in db.SalesReps on w.fldSrId  equals s.pkfSrID
                                     where d.TransTypeID == 1 && d.Product == 0
                                     select new { d.Amount, d.TransTypeID, Name=a.Name.Trim(), a.pkfAgentID, s.pkfSrID, salesrepName = s.Name } into debtRec
                                     group debtRec by new { debtRec.TransTypeID, debtRec.Name, debtRec.pkfAgentID, debtRec.salesrepName, debtRec.pkfSrID } into debtRecGroup
                                     orderby debtRecGroup.Key.Name
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         Sum = debtRecGroup.Sum(model => model.Amount),
                                         TransTypeId = debtRecGroup.Key.TransTypeID,
                                         AgentId = debtRecGroup.Key.pkfAgentID,
                                         AgentName = debtRecGroup.Key.Name.Trim(),
                                         SalesrepId = debtRecGroup.Key.pkfSrID,
                                         SalesRepName = debtRecGroup.Key.salesrepName 
                                     }
```

I need to get the output in just one query, i new to linq to entity. i need the result like:- AgentName     SalesRepName    Debit Total(the total of amount where Product == 0)     Credit Total(total of amount where Product==1)  Outstanding Total(the difference between Debit Total and Credit Total). any suggestion will be appreciable. thanks in advance :)

Comment: You could try to use Concat command to union the to queris to get just one result set.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but i may be possible with group by clause... ;) i am working on it..